# can i list files to someone else's azure blob storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, blob, storage, bucket

Since I work in the security field, I am doing research on deep azure blob storage areas. I would like to explain my problem to you by making a comparison with the aws s3 bucket.

We use the `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname` command to list someone else's s3 bucket. but what kind of command do we need to run to list someone else's azure blob store?

example azure blob storage: `test123.blob.core.windows.net`

Can you tell me what kind of command should be run by this name?

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent command

```
> az storage container list
```